# Generate ordered pairings

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a list of non-repeated objects. I want to extract all the arrangments

```
e.g 
    {A, B, C, D}
    ->
    [A, B, C, D]      
    [A, B, CD]
    [A, BC, D]
    [AB, C, D]
    [AB, CD]
    [ABC, D]
    [A, BCD]
    [ABCD]
```

Order needs to be respected. I can brute force a solution but is there an elegant solution or algorithm I can research to use for the the above problem ?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: This is an order-sensitive partitioning problem.  It boils down to whether or not you place a partition between each pair of objects.  For `N` items, you have `N-1` possible partitions.  Generate the power set of those partitions, and use those to produce your arrangements.

Comment: Thanks Prune that is very helpful. Gave me a direction to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *n* items arrayed in order, then there are n-1 slots in between the items in which a "divider" may be placed. There are thus a total 2^(*n*-1) ways of partitioning the items -- grouping the items that do not have a divider between them for all possible ways of placing dividers.

This translates into C++ code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> GetPartitionFromIndex(const std::vector<T>& items, int index)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> partition = { {} };

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        partition.back().push_back(items[i]);
        if (index & (1 << i))
            partition.push_back({});
    }

    return partition;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> OrderedPartitions(const std::vector<T>& items) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> partitions;
    auto n = (1 << items.size()-1) - 1;
    for (int partition_index = 0; partition_index <= n; partition_index++)
        partitions.push_back(GetPartitionFromIndex(items, partition_index));

    return partitions;
}

int main()
{
    auto test = OrderedPartitions( std::vector<std::string>{ "A", "B", "C", "D" } );
    std::cout << "ordered partitions:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& partitions : test) {
        for (auto& partition : partitions) {
            auto p = std::accumulate(
                std::next(partition.begin()),
                partition.end(),
                partition[0],
                [](std::string a, std::string b) {
                    return a + "," + b;
                }
            );
            std::cout << "{" << p << "} ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

which yields

```
ordered partitions:
{A,B,C,D}
{A} {B,C,D}
{A,B} {C,D}
{A} {B} {C,D}
{A,B,C} {D}
{A} {B,C} {D}
{A,B} {C} {D}
{A} {B} {C} {D}
```

as output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very usefull

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a recursive method. The method would grab the first item in the list for the first element in the output and then recurse with the remaining items in the list.

It would then take the first two items and recurse with the remaining elements.

etc.

It's still brute force.